# I get an error associated with the encoding

Tags: oracle, spring-mvc

I need help. I am sending an http request from the oracle database to Spring mvc. And in return, I get it `HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request` How can I fix this? Added
`utl_http.set_body_charset (req, 'WINDOWS-1251');` and that didn't help either.

With Latin letters, everything works well. As soon as I change to Cyrillic, I get an error

**request(plsql)**

```
declare

content varchar2(4000) := '{"to":"996707332572","from":"Текст","text":"Тест текст"}';

    begin


       req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
       utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
       utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
       utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));
       utl_http.set_body_charset ('UTF-8');
       utl_http.write_text(req, content);

       res := utl_http.get_response(req);
```

**method in controller**

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/send-msg",method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
    public Object sendMsg(@RequestBody SmsBody smsBody) throws Exception
```

Comment: It's most likely a problem with the URL and not the request body. Can you show the URL? And it's probably rejected by the web server before it hits your Spring code.

Comment: And what does the request body look like? Is it JSON, XML or URL encoded data? In the latter case, the URL encoded data might also be the problem.

Comment: @Codo I'll fix the codes in question now.At the beginning I wanted to check whether the data was being transferred correctly. Now I changed the code to send json. Now I get a bad request

Comment: @Codo corrected request code

Comment: The MVC controller specifies `produces = "application/xml; charset=utf-8"`. Against popular believe, this is not an instruction for the controller to generate XML. Instead it's a filter instruction that says: this method may only be used for requests able to accept XML. So you probably need an additional HTTP header: `Accept: application/xml`.

Comment: @Codo 
did like this           `@RequestMapping(value = "/send-msg",method = RequestMethod.POST,
   produces = "application/xml; charset=utf-8",headers="Accept=application/json") `   did not help

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That's the wrong place. Remove it from the Java code and add it to the PL/SQL code instead: `utl_http.set_header(req, 'Accept', 'application/xml');`

Comment: @Codo it didn't help either

Comment: The next likely thing is that your JSON data cannot be converted to an instance of `SmsBody`.

Comment: @Codo yes,
when requested, it writes that it is not a string to parse. Exactly because of the encoding